# SDL cannot find video device within an Xvfb

Tags: sdl, xvfb

I want to run a program that is dependent on SDL 1.2 as a graphics backend within an X virtual frame buffer. I'm using the xvfb-run command like so:

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 -s 'fbdir /tmp/pics' my_program
```

However, I end up getting the following error:

```
Couldn't initialize SDL: No available video device
```

I'm using Compiz as a window manager and am on Ubuntu 14.04. I haven't done any sort of configuration on top of installing the dependencies; is there something I need to do so that a virtual frame buffer can play nice with SDL 1.2?